# Qt style control

Tags: qt, coding-style, appearance

I have a qt app that is defaulting to looking like windows 98. Is there some way to get it to look better? I like the appearance it has on GNOME or KDE, but even getting it to look like windows XP would be an improvement.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using, and on which operating system are you running your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `QApplication::setStyle`:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qapplication.html#setStyle-2

The following code should make your application appear in Windows XP style:

```
QStyle* xpStyle = new QWindowsXPStyle();
QApplication::setStyle(xpStyle);
```

or alternately:

```
QApplication::setStyle("windowsxp");
```

See also:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/style-reference.html